# How do I prevent deleted multi-select picklist values from reappearing after deletion?

Tags: multi-select, pardot

The custom field values on a multi-select picklist just reappeared after I deleted them, and the user who influenced this is our Pardot integration user. How do I prevent this from happening again? I'd like to ensure that our inactive values are deleted after I select "delete" and delete them.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Integration user is trying to add value which is not available in the picklist selection option.

There are two solutions for this.

- Check why different values from available for selection are
  getting added by pardot user.
- Edit the custom picklist field and check on

> Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set

With second option Integration user will not be able add extra picklist values but transactions from Integration user will fail, when user will try to add new picklist option on the record.